# How to push elements to an array and additionally skip default element in the same array

Tags: javascript

Ive got problem with pushing elements to an array and at the same time skip declared deafault element on the same array.

For Example

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let countries = ['Germany','Poland', 'Czechia', 'Slovenia', 'Lithuania', 'Belarus', 'Russia', 'Ukraine'];
let countryNumber = (Math.random() * (countries.length - 1)).toFixed(0);
const allCountries = document.querySelectorAll('.country');
let newCountries = [,'Georgia',];

newCountries.push(countries[countryNumber]);


countries = countries.filter(function (item) {
    return item != countries[countryNumber]
})

countryNumber = (Math.random() * (countries.length - 1)).toFixed(0);

newCountries.push(countries[countryNumber]);

allCountries.forEach(function (country, index) {
    if (index != 1) {
        country.innerHTML = newCountries[index];
    }
})
```

**HTML**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="country"></p>
    <p class="country"></p>
    <p class="country"></p>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect something like(for example):
**Russia
Georgia
Poland**

etc

Comment: `let newCountries = [,'Georgia',];` is this accidental, because this becoming up as undefined.

Comment: You tell us what you expect, but don't tell us what you _actually_ get.

Comment: I get something like
Russia
Georgia
undefinded

Comment: `let newCountries = [,'Georgia',];` creates an array of size=2 containing 2 elements; element[0] is `undefined` and element[1] is "Georgia". `push` [adds elements to the _end_ of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Syntax), so that first `element[0]` is always going to be undefined and "Georgia" will _never_ be in the middle, which is what it seems you want (but you don't really explain the goal). After doing two pushes you should always be ending up with things like `[empty, "Georgia", "Russia", "Slovenia"]

Comment: Oh yes u right, thank you. Any ideas how can i fix it? I tried use „map”. But it does not work well

Comment: It seems to me you could just pick two random countries _first_, then create the newCountries array `let newCountries = [ firstPick, 'Georgia', secondPick ];` but this might be a totally inappropriate approach because I don't know what you're _actually_ trying to accomplish.